# Qt QTreeView - Revert to previous selection when condition not met

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtreeview

On QTreeView selection change, I would like to revert to the previous selection if a certain 
condition is not met.

**For example:**

```
    void Editor::treeFolderSelected(QModelIndex const& index)
    {
        if(widget) {
            if(!widget->trySaveChanges()) {
                //revert to previous, validation failed
                return;
            }
        }

        //do normal behaviour

}
```

Currently I am not seeing a straight forward way to do this, as the `QModelIndex` does not provide any information regarding what was selected previously.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

```
int lastSelection = -1;
bool abortEvent = false;
void Editor::treeFolderSelected(QModelIndex const& index)
{
   if (abortEvent) {
       abortEvent = false;
       return;   
   }
   if(widget) {
     if(!widget->trySaveChanges()) {
        if (lastSelection != -1) {
          abortEvent = true;
          select(lastSelection);
        }  
        return;
      }
      lastSelection = index;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The view selection has its own model, [`QItemSelectionModel`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qitemselectionmodel.html), with signals that give you the new and previous selection.